# How Laravel implicit bound middleware work?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware, authorize

I have to update a Laravel 8/9 application and I have an eli5 question about how implicitly bound middleware work.

I have a logged in route to update an entity as follows:

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'verified']], function () {
  Route::group(['middleware' => ['a.b.c', 'can:update,entity']], function () {
    Route::put('/admin/entity/{entity}', 'App\Http\Controllers\EntityController@updateEntity')->name('entity.updateEntity');
  });
});
```

The `auth`, `verified` and `a.b.c` middlewares I understand, I think:

- `auth`: check the user is logged in (check the auth()->user() return value?). It is a built-in middleware.
- `verified`: check the user email has been verified (check the email_verified_at column in the DB?). It is a built-in middleware.
- `a.b.c`: check the entity exists and can still be modified (custom middleware). It has been written for our application and I checked the code out.

But the `can:update,entity` middleware is implicitly bound, it checks the user can update the entity as I understand, but I cannot understand how the magic happens.

I checked the \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize source code but it still does not click:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Auth\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Authorize
{
    /**
     * The gate instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate
     */
    protected $gate;

    /**
     * Create a new middleware instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate  $gate
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Gate $gate)
    {
        $this->gate = $gate;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string  $ability
     * @param  array|null  ...$models
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $ability, ...$models)
    {
        $this->gate->authorize($ability, $this->getGateArguments($request, $models));

        return $next($request);
    }

    /**
     * Get the arguments parameter for the gate.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  array|null  $models
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|array|string
     */
    protected function getGateArguments($request, $models)
    {
        if (is_null($models)) {
            return [];
        }

        return collect($models)->map(function ($model) use ($request) {
            return $model instanceof Model ? $model : $this->getModel($request, $model);
        })->all();
    }

    /**
     * Get the model to authorize.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string  $model
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|string
     */
    protected function getModel($request, $model)
    {
        if ($this->isClassName($model)) {
            return trim($model);
        } else {
            return $request->route($model, null) ??
                ((preg_match("/^['\"](.*)['\"]$/", trim($model), $matches)) ? $matches[1] : null);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the given string looks like a fully qualified class name.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function isClassName($value)
    {
        return str_contains($value, '\\');
    }
}
```

Like what are the `$gate`, `$ability`?

Can anyone explain to me how it happens under the hood like I'm 5 please?

Comment: These should be written as policies and are well [documented](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization) by Laravel. Check your providers if there are no policies, it is likely they used the `Gate` facade

Comment: Lol, I was not looking in the right spot, I forgot about policies ... Thanks @Jaquarh! I missed the policy and now that I checked it, I can connect the dots at last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Jaquarh, [**Authorization**](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization) is usually implemented via [**Policies**](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#creating-policies), that group authorization logic around a particular model or resource, and that use [**Gates**](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#gates) for single validation objectives.

So how does that translate to my application?

1. There is a policy defined for my *Entities* that is registered in `App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php` in the `policies` property:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\UserEntity;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array<class-string, class-string>
     */
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Models\Entity' => 'App\Policies\EntityPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
    }
}
```

2. The `EntityPolicy` policy is defined in `App\Policies\EntityPolicy.php` and defines what actions can be authorized on *Entities* for the current *User*: create, edit and update.
   ※ Note that all 3 validations are delegated to 2 *Gates*: `can-create-entity` and `user-has-entity`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Entity;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

class EntityPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can create entities.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return bool
     */
    public function create(User $user)
    {
        return Gate::allows('can-create-entity');
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can edit the entity.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Models\Entity  $entity
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function edit(User $user, Entity $entity)
    {
        return Gate::allows('user-has-entity', $entity);
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can update the entity.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Models\Entity  $entity
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function update(User $user, Entity $entity)
    {
        return Gate::allows('user-has-entity', $entity);
    }
}
```

3. *Gates* are defined in the boot method of the `App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider` class using the `Gate` facade like follows:

```
...
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Gate::define('user-has-entity', function($user, $entity) {
            $userEntity = UserEntity::where('user_id', $user->id)
                ->where('entity_id', $entity->id)
                ->first();
            return boolval($userEntity);
        });
        Gate::define('can-create-entity', function($user) {
            $max = config('entities.MAX_AVAILABLE_ENTITIES');
            $now = Carbon::now();
            $current = $user
                        ->entities()
                        ->where('end', '>=', $now)
                        ->count();
            return $current < $max;
        });
    }
...
```

I had read the Laravel documentation page some time ago, but it did not make sense immediately for me, now I think I finally get it and I hope it can help someone else too.